# PlayStore showing "UPDATE" even after updating it to last version

Tags: android, google-play

I'm facing a weird problem. I just released an update of my app in PlayStore. Once the update was live, I updated it from PlayStore in my secondary phone. Now even the app got updated, it still shows "UPDATE"!
[image]

This is my app, showing "UPDATE" button even I updated my app. That's really weird or maybe I missed something(i ain't new into this, I've updated/developed several apps). Maybe I couldn't find a small thing.
What I did-
1. Changed version code to newer(had 11, changed it to 12)
2. Changed version name too

And, PlayStore settings were auto, version code it took automatically(i.e. 12)..what am I missing?
PS- I released my app 2 hrs ago

Edit: Another issue, FirebaseDatabase ain't working on phones which had previous version installed and updated from playstore.. But it works if i uninstall and install it again! 
I guess there's some kinda signature issue..any help pls

Comment: Mukesh: are you using split apks? We have the same issue. Just started using them.

Comment: @MarkAronSzulyovszky afaik,no! I didn't used it. I got this option after updating Android Studio. But i didn't used it.